# Php Mysql display sum using multi dimentional Array

Tags: php, mysql

The source of the below data is a csv file that comes from a warehouse. System reads the csv file and saves in the table called warehouse_feedback. Warehouse splits the quantity and sends in multiple packages. That is the reason here I am having the same EANs multiple times. Here I am forced to save data in the same format as I received from Warehouse. Because I need to send this same data to other ERP system. Another thing is Same EAN will appear under different order ids.

I am able to display information up to some extent. Here is my code to get the below out put.

```
$stmt = $mysqliConn->prepare("SELECT id, hdr_id_fk, package_number, ean, 
                                     quantity, requested_qty, order_number 
                    from warehouse_feedback 
                    where hdr_id_fk =?  ");
$hdr_id = 31;
$stmt->bind_param("i", $hdr_id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$results = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$finalResults = [];
foreach($results as $result){
    $finalResults[$result['ean']][] = $result;
}

<!-- table code -->
<table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Pack_num</th>
                <th>Order Id</th>
                <th>EAN</th>
                <th>ReqQty</th>
                <th>Confrmd Qty</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($finalResults as $finalResult) {
                $confirmedQuantity = 0
            ?>

                <?php foreach ($finalResult as $finalRes) {
                    $confirmedQuantity += $finalRes['quantity'];
                ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $finalRes['id']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $finalRes['package_number']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $finalRes['order_number']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $finalRes['ean']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $finalRes['requested_qty']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $finalRes['quantity']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><?php echo $finalResult[0]['ean']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo 'Req Qty -' . $finalResult[0]['requested_qty'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo 'Confirmed Qty -' . $confirmedQuantity; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here some how my code is not considering Order_number Even the requested quantity is 7 If you see Under ID - 4 it is showing as 6 and same in Under ID - 8 , total requested quantity is 26, and it is showing as 18.

| ID | Pack_num | Order Id | EAN | ReqQty | Confrmd Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3TAI91HB | 4046228076119 | 6 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 3TAI91HB | 4046228076119 | 6 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 3TAI91HB | 4046228076119 | 6 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 6GF4GWRT | 4046228076119 | 1 | 1 |
|  |  |  | **4046228076119** | **Req Qty - 6** | **Confrmd Qty - 6** |
| 5 | 5 | 31C3OD1H | 4046228076729 | 5 | 5 |
|  |  |  | **4046228076729** | **Req Qty - 5** | **Confrmd Qty - 5** |
| 6 | 23 | 1H32M34B | 4046228076123 | 18 | 12 |
| 7 | 24 | 1H32M34B | 4046228076123 | 18 | 3 |
| 8 | 25 | 1H32M34B | 4046228076456 | 8 | 5 |
|  |  |  | **4046228076456** | **Req Qty - 18** | **Confrmd Qty - 20** |

So I would like to have the below result.
Here count should be based on `order_id` and `ean`

| ID | Pack_num | Order Id | EAN | ReqQty | Confrmd Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3TAI91HB | 4046228076119 | 6 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 3TAI91HB | 4046228076119 | 6 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 3TAI91HB | 4046228076119 | 6 | 1 |
|  |  | **3TAI91HB** | **4046228076119** | **Req Qty - 6** | **Confrmd Qty - 5** |
| 4 | 4 | 6GF4GWRT | 4046228076119 | 6 | 6 |
|  |  | **6GF4GWRT** | **4046228076119** | **Req Qty - 6** | **Confrmd Qty - 6** |
| 5 | 5 | 31C3OD1H | 4046228076729 | 5 | 5 |
|  |  | **31C3OD1H** | **4046228076729** | **Req Qty - 5** | **Confrmd Qty - 5** |
| 6 | 23 | 1H32M34B | 4046228076123 | 18 | 12 |
| 7 | 24 | 1H32M34B | 4046228076123 | 18 | 3 |
|  |  | **1H32M34B** | **4046228076123** | **Req Qty - 18** | **Confrmd Qty - 15** |
| 8 | 25 | 1H32M34B | 4046228076456 | 8 | 5 |
|  |  | **1H32M34B** | **4046228076456** | **Req Qty - 8** | **Confrmd Qty - 5** |

`Out put`
[image: Every order id EAN combination is skipping one record]

[image: Some order ids and EAN combination appeared as Requested qty 0 and confirmed qty 0. But this combination not existed in DB]

Comment: The first dimension of your array is `item_number`. Group it by `order_number` to get the result you want.

Comment: Think I have seem this twice already today, in one form or another

Comment: Knowhere in the query do you select a column or alias a column as `item_number` SO how is `$finalResults[$result['item_number']][] = $result;` supposed to work

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I have corrected that. That is ean. not item_number

Comment: No you corrected another line, the one in the foreach loop is still using a non exitant column name

Comment: @RiggsFolly, sorry corrected that. Here the problem is just I have renamed the database table columns.

Comment: Although it isnt narrow enough to the issue, but the question is straight forward, examples given, nicely formatted. Should not get down vote on new user on this

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to my question.

```
<?php
$stmt = $mysqliConn->prepare("SELECT id,hdr_id_fk,package_number,ean,quantity,requested_qty,order_number,sscc_code from desadv_message_lines where hdr_id_fk =? ");
$hdr_id = 31;
$stmt->bind_param("i", $hdr_id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$results = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$finalResults = [];
foreach($results as $result){
    $finalResults[$result['ean']][$result['order_number']][] = $result;
}

?>

<!-- table code -->
<table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Pack_num</th>
                <th>SSCC</th>
                <th>Order Id</th>
                <th>EAN</th>
                <th>ReqQty</th>
                <th>Confrmd Qty</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php 
             foreach ($finalResults as $finalResultItem) {                
                foreach ($finalResultItem as $finalResult) {         
                $confirmedQuantity = 0;

               foreach ($finalResult as $finalRes) {
                    $confirmedQuantity += $finalRes['quantity'];
                    $reqQuantity = $finalRes['requested_qty'];
                ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $finalRes['id']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $finalRes['package_number']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $finalRes['sscc_code']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $finalRes['order_number']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $finalRes['ean']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $finalRes['requested_qty']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $finalRes['quantity']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><?php echo $finalResult[0]['order_number']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $finalResult[0]['ean']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo 'Req Qty -' . $finalResult[0]['requested_qty'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo '<b>Confrmd Qty: ' . $confirmedQuantity.'</b>'; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } }?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```